# Vuejs mount the child components only after data has been loaded

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

What am trying to achieve is to pass data as props in my children components but this data is loaded from the server so it takes a while to load.

I would now like to only mount the children components when the data is fully loaded

SO currently am doing this

IN the parent component

```
<template>
  <child-cmp :value="childdata"></child-cmp>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    data(){
       childdata : [];
     },

     methods:{
      fetchINitData(){
        //fetch from server then
         this.childdata = res.data.items;
         console.log(res.data.items) //has some values

       }

     }


   components:{
     childcmp
    },

   mounted(){
     this.fetchINitData();


     }
    }
 </script>
```

NOw in my child component

```
<script>
export default{
   props:["value];

    mounted(){
      console.log(this.value) //this is always empty
     } 

     }

</script>
```

As from the above example the data passed as props is always empty on the children component. How do i only mount the child component after data has been received or how do i ensure that the childs component get the latest data changed.

Comment: How are you using the data in the child component?  `mounted()` is only called when the component is initially loaded.  Do you have to have the data on load or is it ok for it to be updated later when the server call completes.

Comment: @TimHutchison  am just assigning it to form inputs that it the select dropdowns

Comment: You could bind the empty list to the dropdown right off the bat and then when the list updates the dropdown list will automatically update.  I'll try to add an example later.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `<template v-if="childDataLoaded">`,And load your child component after getting data like this

```
<template>
  <template v-if="childDataLoaded">
    <child-cmp :value="childdata"></child-cmp>
  </template>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    data(){
        childDataLoaded: false,
        childdata : [];
     },
     methods:{
      fetchINitData(){
        //fetch from server then
         this.childdata = res.data.items;
         this.childDataLoaded = true;
         console.log(res.data.items) //has some values
       }
     }
   components:{
     childcmp
    },
   mounted(){
     this.fetchINitData();
     }
    }
 </script>
```

Here is the Nice and cleaner way to update child component.

```js
var child = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>Child Component : {{name}} <div v-if='loading'>Loading...</div></div>",
    props: ['name','loading']
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    data: {
        name: "Niklesh",
        loading: true
    },
    mounted() {
      var vm =  this;
      setTimeout(function() {
         vm.name = "Raut";
          vm.loading = false;
    }, 1000);
    },
    components: {
        child
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
    <child :name="name" :loading="loading"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but may not be the best way to go depending on how you are using the data passed into the child component

Comment: Also works directly on a component, in my case a nest child component I needed to wait for the state to have loaded on mounted before the component could receive dynamic values.
`<article v-if="loaded">
</article>`

Comment: I don't know but using setTimeout is bad approach i think so.

Comment: @htoniv : this is an example, you can use any ajax in your local. this illustrate to load component after some time and that some time would be any http request in form of ajax.

Comment: I like this solution a lot. Putting it into practice to see if any negative side effects arise.

Comment: What will happen If I have to render it anyway. For example it's a form and data is not available in back end. Now I have to set two way binding with child and parent. What to do with that? @NikleshRaut

Answer (score 5):

Just Bind `key` to `child-cmp` you get reactive output. this is simplest method of reactivity in `Vue js`.

```
<template>
  <child-cmp :key="childdata" :value="childdata"></child-cmp>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    data(){
       childdata : [];
     },

     methods:{
      fetchINitData(){
        //fetch from server then
         this.childdata = res.data.items;
         console.log(res.data.items) //has some values
       }
     }

   components:{
     childcmp
    },

   mounted(){
     this.fetchINitData();
     }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Good, but I think its recommended to use a string as a component key. So, it's better to use for the list the length of the Array, or the hash (for data integrity)