# Vue JS Ajax data not populating Vue-Tribute on load

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the Vue Tribute component https://github.com/syropian/vue-tribute

When initially loading the page when the "show" data property is set to true I get "No Match!". However if I set the "show" data property to false on page load then set it to true manually I will get the two results as expected. I have tried to wrap the function call to `getTributeOptions()` inside of "mounted, created and updated" but I receive the same results. I am using the `setTimeout()` to mimic the AJAX call I am using to load the remote data.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: function() {
    return {
      show: true,
      tributeOptions: {
        values: []
      }
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getTributeOptions();
  },
  methods: {
    getTributeOptions: function(resource) {
      var vm = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
         vm.tributeOptions.values = [
            { key: 'Phil Heartman', value: 'pheartman' },
            { key: 'Gordon Ramsey', value: 'gramsey' }
          ];
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})

<div id="myApp">
  <div v-if="show">
    <vue-tribute :options="tributeOptions">
      <input type="text" placeholder="@" />
    </vue-tribute>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBQaNB?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on this question: [Vuejs mount the child components only after data has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731440/vuejs-mount-the-child-components-only-after-data-has-been-loaded)

Updated Code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: function() {
    return {
      userDataLoaded: false,
      tributeOptions: {
        values: []
      }
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getTributeOptions();
  },
  methods: {
    getTributeOptions: function(resource) {
      var vm = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
         vm.tributeOptions.values = [
            { key: 'Phil Heartman', value: 'pheartman' },
            { key: 'Gordon Ramsey', value: 'gramsey' }
          ];
        vm.dataLoaded = true;
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})

<div id="myApp">
  <template>
    <template v-if="dataLoaded">
      <vue-tribute :options="tributeOptions">
        <input type="text" placeholder="@" />
      </vue-tribute>
    </template>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: actually what you do is rebuild(remount) the components inside `v-if`. The best way should be add one watcher to `vue-tribute`, then watch `options`, if change, delete old instance then create new instance instead. Then parent component don't need to care force-remount etc.

Answer (score 1):

While your workaround above would probably work, the problem lays in the library you use
In https://github.com/syropian/vue-tribute/blob/master/src/index.js#L19

```
mounted() {
  const $el = this.$slots.default[0].elm;

  this.tribute = new Tribute(this.options);
...
}
```

The `options` value is only used once in `mounted()`, and there is no handler for updating the values when the options are changed.

A better way to do it would be to `watch` for changes in `this.options`, and update the value inside the component respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Vue Tribute source code at Github](https://github.com/syropian/vue-tribute/blob/master/src/index.js#L19), you will see it will only create one `new Tribute` instance in mounted(). That means even you change the value of props=options once mounted, it will not affect anything.

So one solution is make sure tributeOptions is ready before mount, so update the value in `created()` will be an idea.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: function() {
    return {
      tributeOptions: {
        values: []
      }
    };
  },
  created: function () {
   this.tributeOptions.values = [
      { key: 'Phil Heartman', value: 'pheartman' },
      { key: 'Gordon Ramsey', value: 'gramsey' }
    ]
  },
  mounted: function() {
    //this.getTributeOptions();
  },
  methods: {
    getTributeOptions: function(resource) {
      var vm = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
         vm.tributeOptions.values = [
            { key: 'Phil Heartman', value: 'pheartman' },
            { key: 'Gordon Ramsey', value: 'gramsey' }
          ];
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-tribute"></script>
<div id="myApp">
    <vue-tribute :options="tributeOptions">
      <input type="text" placeholder="@" />
    </vue-tribute>
</div>
```

another solution is download the source codes for **Vue Tribute** in Github, then implement `update Tribute instance` by yourself.

**Update**: create [one pull request](https://github.com/syropian/vue-tribute/pull/6) which implement `update Tribute options`.

the third solution will be **force re-mount** by bind different key every time once `tributeOptions` is updated:

like below demo.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: function() {
    return {
      tributeOptions: {
        values: []
      },
      tributeKey: 0
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getTributeOptions();
  },
  methods: {
    getTributeOptions: function(resource) {
      var vm = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
         vm.tributeOptions.values = [
            { key: 'Phil Heartman', value: 'pheartman' },
            { key: 'Gordon Ramsey', value: 'gramsey' }
          ];
          vm.tributeKey+=1
      }, 500)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-tribute"></script>
<div id="myApp">
    <vue-tribute :options="tributeOptions" :key="tributeKey">
      <input type="text" placeholder="@" />
    </vue-tribute>
</div>
```

Comment: @Yamaha32088 I just created [one pull request](https://github.com/syropian/vue-tribute/pull/6) which implement 'update Tribute options'. You can take that one to try it.