# Vue JS, how to make axios request API running first before HTML DOM component loaded?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm still learning this VueJS with Laravel, what I want to do is to get the categories data from API and load it into the select dropdown, but I found that this Axios request running too long.

here's the snippet code

```
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            category: 0,
            categories: [],
            loading: true,
        }
    },
    async created() {
        let uri = '/api/getCategory';
        axios.get(uri).then(response => {
            this.categories = response.data;
            console.log('2');
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
            .finally(() => {
                this.loading = false;
            });
        console.log('1');
    },
    methods: {
            loadCategories() {
            axios.get('/api/getCategory')
                .then(response => this.categories = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
}
```

based on this.
1 
DOM LOADED
2

is there a way to make my Axios API request to fetch the data first before the HTML finish loaded?

Comment: please check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077104/when-to-use-the-lifecycle-method-beforemount-in-vue-js

Comment: check this link also : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46731440/2815635

Comment: did you tried `beforeMount()` hook?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access reactive data before the *created* hook. Axios is made up for reactive processing which means once the data are available they will be displayed. 
The solutions I am suggesting are the below :

1. You could request the data on a parent component and store it in *localStorage* for example. You could use it anywhere in the application then.
2. Keep your code in the *created* hook. Use a computed property instead of *categories* for instant rendering.

   computed:{ 
     computedCategories(){ 
       return this.categories; 
     }
   }
3. You definitely have to check your server side code for query enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to reduce the response time of the request, I suggest you implement some kind of visual loading indication, maybe on the select input. Could be a spinner or a small "Loading..." text.

Having the request in a parent component for example, won't make up for the fact that the request response time is slow and will be a bad experience for the user, with no indication that the component is loading/fetching data.

If the problem is that you get render errors, because `categories` is not yet available to the DOM, you can use a conditional render `v-if="categories.length"`, to only render the elements with data, when it's available.